# Oracle SQL Adding IF statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a pretty simple question me thinks.  I've been looking on the internet, but haven't been able to find anything.  I am trying to add an IF statement basically to my Oracle sql.

```
UPDATE PS_Z_TREND_NOW_TBL a 
  SET STATUS = ( 
 SELECT COUNT(SEC.IS_AW_AUTH_NAME) 
  FROM PS_IS_AW_SECURITY sec 
 WHERE sec.IS_AW_AUTH_NAME LIKE '%Manager%'
```

I want to update STATUS so that if `COUNT(SEC.IS_AW_AUTH_NAME)` is greater than 0 it will insert 'M'.  How would I write this?

Comment: USE `CASE` statements

Comment: Are you sure that you want `PS_Z_TREND_NOW_TBL` updated for all records if the `COUNT(SEC.IS_AW_AUTH_NAME)` is greater than 0? Could it be that you want this done only when `a.is_aw_auth_name = sec.is_aw_auth_name`.  Could it be that you want to use a correlated subquery in your where clause or merge statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `Case` statements.

```
UPDATE PS_Z_TREND_NOW_TBL a 
  SET STATUS = ( CASE WHEN COUNT(SEC.IS_AW_AUTH_NAME)  > 0 then 'M'
                 ELSE null END )
FROM PS_IS_AW_SECURITY sec 
WHERE sec.IS_AW_AUTH_NAME LIKE '%Manager%'
```